# Floating table cells

Tags: html, css, css-float

How can I float td's within a table?

I have the following table:

```
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td>Huge IMAGE</td>
<td>VERY long TEXT</td>
<td>Annotations</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now I'd like the td-cells to move like this (but with floats) when a small end user device loads this view:

```
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td>Huge IMAGE</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>VERY long TEXT</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Annotations</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why are you using tables?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? It seems you've realized you want things to wrap on smaller devices (which tables are really bad at). Is that why you're trying to switch to floats?

Comment: Are you looking for a pure CSS solution? Just about anything can be achieved with JS

Comment: Stop where you are.  Stop using tables.  Re-learn HTML5 semantics.  Then proceed.  You will answer your own question easily.

Comment: This is exactly why we don't use tables for structure anymore... they lack the flexibility that varied screen sizes demand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly advise that you use a nested div structure instead of tables for your layout.

```
<div class="outerContainer">
     <div class="imageHolder"></div>
     <div class="textDescHolder"></div>
     <div class="annotations"></div>
</div>
```

Then use "display: inline-block" on the inner div elements to control the layout. Although I am unclear as to how you wish to display the text and annotations in relation to the images.

Comment: This solution seems best at the moment. The other solutions are great and would work, too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly, what you want to do, but does it have to be a table? Maybe you should use an unordered list instead. In this list you can float your list items.

Something like:

http://jsfiddle.net/7kM48/

CSS

```
ul li{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    list-style: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li style="background-color: yellow;">Content 1</li>
    <li style="background-color: fuchsia;">Content 2</li>
    <li style="background-color: green;">Content 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I would but I can't due to reputation limitations. Is that a reason for a downvote? I just wanted to help...

Comment: @schlonzo Newbies have to earn your keep here, that means contibuting with actual answers before you have full access.  Just because you can post an answer doesn't mean you can use an answer to make a comment.  You're almost there, you'll be able to comment soon!

Comment: I certainly do not want to discourage you, but using lists for content is a bad idea. There is such a thing as writing intuitive code, and this is more or less the opposite of that. Instead, with the non-supportive IE7 having left the building, I would suggest to just use divs, with a `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using columns from bootstrap:

```
<div class="container" style="text-align: center">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        Huge Image
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        Very long text
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
        Annotations
    </div>
</div>
```

this way you have the same output in a normal screen, and one row each for a small device

Comment: This assumes user is using bootstrap?

Comment: Yes, forgot to mention that